# Only View Some ADLS containers based on RBAC

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-storage-account

For Azure Data lake, I have many containers related to different teams, (team1, team2,...)
they already have RBAC, but even if each team can manage its own container, but they still can see other containers displayed
Now my question is, can I display only the container based on their role, so each team can see his containers only?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `Storage Blob Data Contributor` Role to each container for each team that needs to access it. And the `Reader` Role to all teams on the Storage account so that they see the resource in Azure. Then, every team can only see the content of the assigned container.